# Hql query to Criteria query

Tags: java, sql, hql, criteria

I have this sentence that's works correctly in HQL:

String queryString =

```
"SELECT gmr.id.expedientId.idEns as idEns,"
            + " gmr.id.expedientId.anyExp as anyExp,"
            + " gmr.id.expedientId.numExp as numExp,"
            + " gmr.id.numOrdre as numOrdre,"
            + " gmr.idRecursRebuig.desRecursRebuig as descripcioRebuig,"
            + " gmr.desAmpliRebuig as observacionsRebuig,"
            + " gmr.tipusRebuig as tipusRebuig"
            + " FROM GirMotiuRebuig gmr"
            + " where gmr.id.expedientId.idEns =:idEns and"
            + " gmr.id.expedientId.anyExp =:anyExp and"
            + " gmr.id.expedientId.numExp =:numExp"
            + " ORDER BY gmr.id.numOrdre";

            Query queryObject = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()
                    .createQuery(queryString);

            queryObject.setResultTransformer(Transformers
                    .aliasToBean(MotiusRebuig.class));

            queryObject.setParameter("idEns",clauExpedient.getIdEns());
            queryObject.setParameter("anyExp",clauExpedient.getAnyExp());
            queryObject.setParameter("numExp",clauExpedient.getNumExp());

            llistaMotiusRebuig =queryObject.list();
```

and my criteria version:

```
Criteria consulta = this.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()
    .createCriteria(GirMotiuRebuig.class)
    .add(Restrictions.eq("id.expedientId.idEns", clauExpedient.getIdEns()))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("id.expedientId.anyExp", clauExpedient.getAnyExp()))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("id.expedientId.numExp", clauExpedient.getNumExp()))
    .addOrder(Order.asc("id.numOrdre"))
    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
    .add(Projections.property("id.expedientId.idEns"),"idEns")
    .add(Projections.property("id.expedientId.anyExp"),"anyExp")
    .add(Projections.property("id.expedientId.numExp"),"numExp")
    .add(Projections.property("id.numOrdre"),"numOrdre")
        .add(Projections.property("idRecursRebuig.desRecursRebuig"),"descripcioRebuig")
    .add(Projections.property("desAmpliRebuig"),"observacionsRebuig")
    .add(Projections.property("tipusRebuig"),"tipusRebuig")
    .add(Projections.property("expedientId.numOrdre"),"numOrdre"))
                .setResultTransformer(
                Transformers.aliasToBean(MotiusRebuig.class));
    llistaMotiusRebuig =  consulta.list();
```

And exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: idRecursRebuig.desRecursRebuig of: cat.base.gir.logica.domini.impl.GirMotiuRebuig
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:44)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:38)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1362)
        at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getType(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:477)
        at org.hibernate.criterion.PropertyProjection.getTypes(PropertyProjection.java:36)
        at org.hibernate.criterion.AliasedProjection.getTypes(AliasedProjection.java:37)
        at org.hibernate.criterion.ProjectionList.getTypes(ProjectionList.java:38)
        at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getProjectedTypes(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:318)
        at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker.<init>(CriteriaJoinWalker.java:77)
        at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker.<init>(CriteriaJoinWalker.java:59)
        at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.<init>(CriteriaLoader.java:67)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1550)
        at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:283)
        at cat.base.gir.dao.GirMotiuRebuigDao.obtenirMotiusRebuig(GirMotiuRebuigDao.java:73)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at $Proxy1183.obtenirMotiusRebuig(Unknown Source)
        at cat.base.gir.serveis.GirRecursService.obtenirMotiusRebuig(GirRecursService.java:381)
        ... 127 more
```

Entity: GirMotiuRebuig

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "gir_exp_motiu_rebuig")
public class GirMotiuRebuig implements IGirMotiuRebuig {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5587115692447683913L;

    private ExpedientIdMultiple id;
    private MRecursRebuig idRecursRebuig;
    private String desAmpliRebuig;
    private GirExpedient expedientGir;
    protected Integer tipusRebuig;

    public GirMotiuRebuig() {
    }

    public GirMotiuRebuig(ExpedientIdMultiple id, MRecursRebuig idRecursRebuig, String desAmpliRebuig,
            GirExpedient expedientGir) {
        this.id = id;
        this.idRecursRebuig = idRecursRebuig;
        this.desAmpliRebuig = desAmpliRebuig;
        this.expedientGir = expedientGir;
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides( {
            @AttributeOverride(name = "expedientId.idEns", column = @Column(name = "id_ens", nullable = false, precision = 5, scale = 0)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "expedientId.anyExp", column = @Column(name = "any_exp", nullable = false, precision = 4, scale = 0)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "expedientId.numExp", column = @Column(name = "num_exp", nullable = false, precision = 10, scale = 0)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "numOrdre", column = @Column(name = "num_ordre", nullable = false, precision = 10, scale = 0)) })
    public ExpedientIdMultiple getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(ExpedientIdMultiple id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_recurs_rebuig")
    public MRecursRebuig getIdRecursRebuig() {
        return idRecursRebuig;
    }

    public void setIdRecursRebuig(MRecursRebuig idRecursRebuig) {
        this.idRecursRebuig = idRecursRebuig;
    }

    @Column(name = "des_ampli_rebuig", nullable = false, length = 250)
    public String getDesAmpliRebuig() {
        return desAmpliRebuig;
    }

    public void setDesAmpliRebuig(String desAmpliRebuig) {
        this.desAmpliRebuig = desAmpliRebuig;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns( {
            @JoinColumn(name = "id_ens", referencedColumnName = "id_ens", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "any_exp", referencedColumnName = "any_exp", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "num_exp", referencedColumnName = "num_exp", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false) })
    public GirExpedient getExpedientGir() {
        return expedientGir;
    }

    public void setExpedientGir(GirExpedient expedientGir) {
        this.expedientGir = expedientGir;
    }

    @Column(name = "tipus_rebuig", nullable = false)
    public Integer getTipusRebuig() {
        return tipusRebuig;
    }

    public void setTipusRebuig(Integer tipusRebuig) {
        this.tipusRebuig = tipusRebuig;
    }
```

well, this criteria works:

```
Criteria consulta = this.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()
                .createCriteria(GirMotiuRebuig.class, "g")
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("g.id.expedientId.idEns", clauExpedient.getIdEns()))
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("g.id.expedientId.anyExp", clauExpedient.getAnyExp()))
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("g.id.expedientId.numExp", clauExpedient.getNumExp()))
                    .addOrder(Order.asc("g.id.numOrdre"))
                .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                        .add(Projections.property("g.id.expedientId.idEns"),"idEns")
                        .add(Projections.property("g.id.expedientId.anyExp"),"anyExp")
                        .add(Projections.property("g.id.expedientId.numExp"),"numExp")
                        .add(Projections.property("g.desAmpliRebuig"),"observacionsRebuig")
                        .add(Projections.property("g.id.numOrdre"),"numOrdre")
                        .add(Projections.property("g.tipusRebuig"),"tipusRebuig")
                        )
                .setResultTransformer(
                        Transformers.aliasToBean(MotiusRebuig.class));
        llistaMotiusRebuig =  consulta.list();
```

but when i try to attack "idRecursRebuig.desRecursRebuig as descripcioRebuig"
like:

```
Criteria consulta = this.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()
                    .createCriteria(GirMotiuRebuig.class, "g")
                        .add(Restrictions.eq("g.id.expedientId.idEns", clauExpedient.getIdEns()))
                        .add(Restrictions.eq("g.id.expedientId.anyExp", clauExpedient.getAnyExp()))
                        .add(Restrictions.eq("g.id.expedientId.numExp", clauExpedient.getNumExp()))
                        .addOrder(Order.asc("g.id.numOrdre"))
                    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                            .add(Projections.property("g.id.expedientId.idEns"),"idEns")
                            .add(Projections.property("g.id.expedientId.anyExp"),"anyExp")
                            .add(Projections.property("g.id.expedientId.numExp"),"numExp")
                            .add(Projections.property("g.desAmpliRebuig"),"observacionsRebuig")
                            .add(Projections.property("g.id.numOrdre"),"numOrdre")
                            .add(Projections.property("g.tipusRebuig"),"tipusRebuig")
                            **.add(Projections.property("g.idRecursRebuig.desRecursRebuig"),"descripcioRebuig")**
                            )
                    .setResultTransformer(
                            Transformers.aliasToBean(MotiusRebuig.class));
            llistaMotiusRebuig =  consulta.list();
```

the query fails...

```
nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: idRecursRebuig.desRecursRebuig of: cat.base.gir.logica.domini.impl.GirMotiuRebuig
```

so:the problem is when i try to recuperate idRecurs...so..i need extra cafein...

this is the mapping of MRecursRebuig:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MRecursRebuig")
public class MRecursRebuig implements IMRecursRebuig {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7439723582297629986L;

    private Integer idRecursRebuig;
    private String desRecursRebuig;
    private Integer tipusRebuig;

    public MRecursRebuig() {
    }

    public MRecursRebuig(Integer idRecursRebuig, String desRecursRebuig) {
        this.idRecursRebuig = idRecursRebuig;
        this.desRecursRebuig = desRecursRebuig;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_recurs_rebuig", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 22, scale = 0)
    public Integer getIdRecursRebuig() {
        return idRecursRebuig;
    }

    public void setIdRecursRebuig(Integer idRecursRebuig) {
        this.idRecursRebuig = idRecursRebuig;
    }

    @Column(name = "des_recurs_rebuig", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getDesRecursRebuig() {
        return desRecursRebuig;
    }

    public void setDesRecursRebuig(String desRecursRebuig) {
        this.desRecursRebuig = desRecursRebuig;
    }

    @Column(name = "tipus_rebuig", nullable = false)
    public Integer getTipusRebuig() {
        return tipusRebuig;
    }
```

and if i try this:

```
Criteria consulta = this.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()
                    .createCriteria(GirMotiuRebuig.class, "g")
                    .createAlias("g.idRecursRebuig", "idRecursRebuig")
                        .add(Restrictions.eq("g.id.expedientId.idEns", clauExpedient.getIdEns()))
                        .add(Restrictions.eq("g.id.expedientId.anyExp", clauExpedient.getAnyExp()))
                        .add(Restrictions.eq("g.id.expedientId.numExp", clauExpedient.getNumExp()))
                        .add(Restrictions.eq("g.idRecursRebuig", clauExpedient.getNumExp()))
                        .addOrder(Order.asc("g.id.numOrdre"))
                    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                            .add(Projections.property("g.id.expedientId.idEns"),"idEns")
                            .add(Projections.property("g.id.expedientId.anyExp"),"anyExp")
                            .add(Projections.property("g.id.expedientId.numExp"),"numExp")
                            .add(Projections.property("g.desAmpliRebuig"),"observacionsRebuig")
                            .add(Projections.property("g.id.numOrdre"),"numOrdre")
                            .add(Projections.property("g.tipusRebuig"),"tipusRebuig")
                            **.add(Projections.property("idRecursRebuig.desRecursRebuig"),"descripcioRebuig")**
                            )
                    .setResultTransformer(
                            Transformers.aliasToBean(MotiusRebuig.class));
            llistaMotiusRebuig =  consulta.list();
```

I receive:

```
nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of cat.base.gir.logica.domini.impl.MRecursRebuig.idRecursRebuig
    cat.base.gir.serveis.GirRecursService.obtenirMotiusRebuig(GirRecursService.java:387)
```

Comment: It's hard to say anything when we even don't know whether GirMotiuRebuig class contains desRecursRebuig property. Maybe please check first if such property exist there...

Comment: well hql sentence works, but not in criteria...so property exists, maybe i don't understand how it works..

Comment: Swap `.add(Projections.property("idRecursRebuig.desRecursRebuig"),"descripcioRebuig")` with `.add(Projections.property("desAmpliRebuig"),"observacionsRebuig")`, run it, and tell us if the output changes at all.

Comment: same mistake...wtf...ty for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a HQL query, when you have something like

```
select entityA.entityB.foo from EntityA entityA ...
```

you're in fact creating an implicit inner join between EntityA and EntityB. It's equivalent to

```
select entityB.foo from EntityA entityA
inner join entityA.entityB entityB ...
```

In Criteria queries, you can't chain properties like you're doing in HQL. Instead, each time a join is needed, you must create it explicitely, using a subCriteria or (my preference) an alias. So you need to do

```
Criteria consulta = this.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()
    .createCriteria(GirMotiuRebuig.class, "girMotiuRebuig")
    .createAlias("girMotiuRebuig.id.expedientId", "expedient") 
    .add(Restrictions.eq("expedient.idEns", clauExpedient.getIdEns()))
    ...
```

Note that your design and naming makes your code hard to understand. You should avoid composite keys by all means, and you shouldn't name `idRecursRebuig` a field which is actually an instance of MRecursRebuig, and is not an ID at all.

Comment: sorry for being hard to understand, tomorrow i change.

Answer (score 0):

well I feel closer to monkeys every day, finally the solution is:

```
Criteria consulta = this.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()
                    .createCriteria(GirMotiuRebuig.class, "g")
                    .createAlias("idRecursRebuig", "i")
                        .add(Restrictions.eq("g.id.expedientId.idEns", clauExpedient.getIdEns()))
                        .add(Restrictions.eq("g.id.expedientId.anyExp", clauExpedient.getAnyExp()))
                        .add(Restrictions.eq("g.id.expedientId.numExp", clauExpedient.getNumExp()))
                        .addOrder(Order.asc("g.id.numOrdre"))
                    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                            .add(Projections.property("g.id.expedientId.idEns"),"idEns")
                            .add(Projections.property("g.id.expedientId.anyExp"),"anyExp")
                            .add(Projections.property("g.id.expedientId.numExp"),"numExp")
                            .add(Projections.property("g.desAmpliRebuig"),"observacionsRebuig")
                            .add(Projections.property("g.id.numOrdre"),"numOrdre")
                            .add(Projections.property("g.tipusRebuig"),"tipusRebuig")
                            .add(Projections.property("i.desRecursRebuig"),"descripcioRebuig")
                            )
                    .setResultTransformer(
                            Transformers.aliasToBean(MotiusRebuig.class));
            llistaMotiusRebuig =  consulta.list();
```